# Nilpotent and adjoint

Tags: linear-algebra, adjoint-operators

Prove that if a function f $\in \mathcal{L}(V,V)$ is nilpotent then its adjoint $f^{*}$ is also nilpotent and they have the same integer such that $f^m=0$ and $(f^{*})^m=0$.

Should I begin this problem with the scalar product and with the help of a orthogonal basis? And I also only know that the matrix representation equation $[f]_{B,B}^H=[f^*]_{B,B}$, where the notation H is hermitian transpose and B the orthogonal basis of V.
Could you please give me some advices?

Comment: You are on the right track. Suppose $A$ is the matrix of $f$ under a given basis, then $A^H$ is the matrix of $f^*$ under the same basis. Now use $(A^H)^m = (A^m)^H$.

Comment: I would show that $(f^*)^n = (f^n)^*$ for all $n$, by induction. This follows from the fact that $(fg)^* = g^* f^*$ for all $f$ and $g$.

Comment: Thank you guys, really appreciate your advices!